# iOS App with Parse not showing in Facebook App Settings & Permissions after Facebook Login

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, swift, parse-platform

I have implemented Facebook login with Parse using the following script on button click :-

```
    var permissions = ["public_profile", "email"]

    PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions) {
        (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if let user = user {
            if user.isNew {
                print("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")

                let grapthRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id,name,gender"])
                grapthRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in

                    if error != nil
                    {
                        print(error)
                    }

                    else if let result = result
                    {
                        print(result)
                    }

                })
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showTabs", sender: self)

            } else {
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showTabs", sender: self)
                print("User logged in through Facebook!")
            }
        } else {
            print("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")
        }
    }
```

Everything works fine, however, the app doesn't show on my Facebook app settings page. This means the app is always authorized and I cannot remove permissions? Why is this happening?

[image]

Comment: Do you have your app already in production?

Comment: Yes. I have activated it in production.

Comment: Mmm if it is activated you should definitively see it in your Apps settings :/

Comment: Ok I figured it out ... Its logged into my other facebook account .. This is because its using the account I logged into from safari , rather than the facebook app. Why is this? Shouldn't the facebook app have preference?

Comment: I think Parse use safari with the parse scheme rather than the FB app, could be good or bad because FB changed a lot their SDK lately